# Video appears to be of different colour on different OS/screens

Tags: ffmpeg, video-processing

I have a `video.mp4` which has a purple background colour. I want to place this video on my webpage, with the same purple background, so that the video looks like part of it.

On a website, I have the same purple background, and the video should blend in. However, on different screens, it appears as a slightly different shade of purple. Is it possible to re-encode the video to be consistent across all screens?

I do not have access to the source file, only to the `video.mp4`.

After searching, I [found this answer](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/32075/yuv-to-rgb-srgb-color-space-conversion-using-ffmpeg), however, it produces a 'broken' video.

Comment: With the same player?  Maybe ask superuser...

Comment: @rogerdpack It's a webpage, displaying a video (via Chrome)

Comment: Why not sample the purple from video itself (read 1 pixel via canvas) and use the same colour code as the new RGB of your background?  Meaning... load the video, draw to canvas, get a purple pixel position and read the RGB colour code then use JS to update your bg colour.

Comment: See [Your browser and my browser see different colors](https://mux.com/blog/your-browser-and-my-browser-see-different-colors/)